# When did HTTP start compressing text?

Tags: history, internet, compression, web-browser

HTML tends to compress well, typically consisting of text interspersed with repetitive tags. Transparently compressing it for download is a fairly obvious optimization to save bandwidth.

When did Web servers start routinely doing this? [Mozilla's development pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Evolution_of_HTTP) mentions that HTTP/2 in 2015 started compressing *headers*, but doesn't seem to say anything about compression of text in document *bodies*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a contemporary subject better-suited to SO, SU, or similar.

Comment: agreed - gopher: that's definitely retro. ftp, though older, is still (barely) in use so for some questions yes but for most no. http/1.0: not at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree, HTTP isn't exactly retro. Not even 0.9 as many servers still support it. Then again, I would like to read this more of a historic question which can be on topic - even though it's not _well formed_ :))

Comment: With a lot of HTTP libraries it is still pretty hard (i.e. not just setting an intuitive config option) to compress both request and response body.

Comment: @AndreKR Libraries aren't exactly an argument when it's about (standard) usage is. At best they document individual choices and application expectation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Compression of document bodies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Compression) is negotiated between clients and servers (and proxies), using notably [the `Accept-Encoding` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding): the client indicates which compression algorithms it supports, and the server chooses one as appropriate for the content being served (*e.g.* a JPEG file shouldn’t be compressed again) and the context of the negotiation (*e.g.* TLS sessions can be compressed, so there’s no point in serving compressed content in that context).

HTTP/1.0 (1996) already supported [`compress` and `gzip`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-3.5); more were [added in HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5). Compression was supported before HTTP/1.0 was published, at least by [CERN httpd](https://www.w3.org/Daemon) (in 1994). The use of compression was common early on: GIF and JPEG for images of course, and dynamically-negotiated compression for text. I don’t have historical references for the latter but I do remember it being a common part of setting up a web server in the nineties (although mis-configured servers weren’t rare).

Comment: Around 2005-2010 there was a well known bug or exploit (forgot the details) involving IE when accepting compression. Servers were routinely configured to automatically compress text except when IE is detected.

Comment: Note that in 1994, according to W3C there were only [623 web servers](https://twitter.com/w3c/status/1179909748147343361).

Comment: @T.E.D. Those early-mid 90s figures look a bit dubious from memory

Comment: @MickO'Hea - You might know better than me, but I think that's about the year I first started using the Web, and for a while indexes rather than search engines were a perfectly reasonable way to look around. It was a year or two before I had to give up on indexes and start just searching for sites. In fact, it was a while before it became more useful for me than gopher.

Answer (score 11):

http/0.9 didn't have any headers, and so couldn't support compression.

On the other hand, http/1.0 ([rfc1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945), May 1996) already had that support. It was already on [draft-00](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-fielding-http-spec-00.ps) (as `Content-Encoding: x-gzip`), dated November 28, 1994.

Do note that HTTP/1.0 was first implemented, then published as an informational RFC. See [one of the first messages on the working group](https://web.archive.org/web/20000818222638/http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/http/hypermail/1994q4/0033.html).

This [1992 version of HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html) already included [Content-Encoding](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Object_Headers.html#content-encoding) (despite the title, I suspect the page contents might reflect a later year than 1992, though)

First version of gzip program (gzip 0.1) was first publicly released on 31 October 1992, and version 1.0 followed in February 1993. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip))

Thus, compression support must have been added to http around 1992-1993.

Of note, [NCSA Mosaic](https://github.com/alandipert/ncsa-mosaic) (started around those dates) doesn't support Content-Encoding header.

Since Content-Encoding is a negotiated header in HTTP, it is transparent, as soon as clients started using HTTP/1.0 the servers would have started compressing responses when they could (i.e. almost on every static file they served).

Answer (score 4):

I surfed the entire web once -- I fired up NCSA Mosaic, found there were only about a dozen web sites up at  the time, and pulled up at least the front page on all of them. I don't recall Netscape 0.9 (came out in 1994) supporting HTTP compression.  But my recollection is by 1995 or so, HTTP compression was already fairly widespread.